# CSS - how to show a child div over parent without overflow

Tags: css, slider

I am using a Wordpress plugin which has a slider with thumbnails. In the thumbnails there are previous and next arrows.

An example demo is here: http://demo.weblizar.com/ultimate-responsive-image-slider-pro/slider-layout-3/ (Style B)

If you go to Style B and hover over the thumbnails you will see prev/next arrows. I want to move the arrows so they are outside of the images, however if I change this CSS:

```
.sp-bottom-thumbnails .sp-next-thumbnail-arrow, .sp-top-thumbnails .sp-next-thumbnail-arrow {
    right: -8px;
    background: red;
```

}

The arrow will just disappear. The only way I've so far managed to get the arrows displaying further is applying a larger width than the parent to the div which has the arrows and use left/right then setting overflow to visible on the parent. This however, will show all of the thumbnails.

What I want is for the arrows to be next to the end of the thumbnails and not on top of the thumbnail images.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Instead just adding a modifcation  like `sp-thumbnail-container { padding: 0 10px }` will do the trick (and you need to change the color of the arrows). This makes the thumbnail area 10px narrower on either side creating room for the arrows.